# Handle Android system back button in Flutter app with nested navigators

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, back

I have a Flutter app composed of "sub-apps" with different theme colors.
In a sub-app, the AppBar's back button is working as expected: it navigates back to the previous sub-app page.
However the Android system's back button is NOT working as expected: it navigates directly to the root app.

The expected back navigation in the following example should be: B3 B2 B1 A3 A2 A1. But it's B3 A3 A2 A1.

In other words, I want the Android back button to work the same way as the Flutter back button.

The same problem happens with iOS "back swipe" gesture (iosPageTransition = true).

Please try the following code on an Android device or emulator and test with the system's back button.

Note that I use multiple MaterialApps to apply a color theme to all screens of a sub-app.

Also note that `WillPopScope` doesn't work since it's not triggered by the system's back button.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(_AppA(_PageA(1)));
}

class _ColoredApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color color;
  final Widget home;
  final iosPageTransition = false;
  _ColoredApp(this.color, this.home);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(primary: color),
        pageTransitionsTheme: iosPageTransition
            ? PageTransitionsTheme(
                builders: Map.fromIterable(
                  TargetPlatform.values,
                  value: (_) => const CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilder(),
                ),
              )
            : null,
      ),
      home: home,
    );
  }
}

class _AppA extends _ColoredApp {
  _AppA(Widget home) : super(Colors.red, home);
}

class _AppB extends _ColoredApp {
  _AppB(Widget home) : super(Colors.green, home);
}

class _PageA extends StatelessWidget {
  final int number;
  const _PageA(this.number);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('A$number')),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text('Next'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
              if (number > 2) return _AppB(_PageB(1));
              return _PageA(number + 1);
            }));
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _PageB extends StatelessWidget {
  final int number;
  const _PageB(this.number);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var scaffold = Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: number == 1 ? BackButton(onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop()) : null,
        title: Text('B$number'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text('Next'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
              return _PageB(number + 1);
            }));
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
    return scaffold;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can't set two MaterialApp in single flutter app its wrong way to use it, in your code it initialize 2 times.Just change your theme from the page you want to update,

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  final iosPageTransition = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: _PageA(1),
    );
  }
}

class _PageA extends StatelessWidget {
  final int number;
  const _PageA(this.number);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return

      Theme(
        data: ThemeData(
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(primary: Colors.red),
        ),
        child: Builder(
            builder: (context) {
              return  Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(title: Text('A$number')),
                body: Center(
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    child: Text('Next'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                        if (number > 2) return _PageB(1);
                        return _PageA(number + 1);
                      }));
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
        ),
      );
  }
}

class _PageB extends StatelessWidget {

  final int number;
  const _PageB(this.number);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

   return

     Theme(
       data: ThemeData(
         colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(primary: Colors.blue),
       ),
       child: Builder(
           builder: (context) {
             return  Scaffold(
               appBar: AppBar(
                 leading: BackButton(onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context)) ,
                 title: Text('B$number'),
               ),
               body: Center(
                 child: ElevatedButton(
                   child: Text('Next'),
                   onPressed: () {
                     Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                       return _PageB(number + 1);
                     }));
                   },
                 ),
               ),
             );
           }
       ),
     );

  }
}
```

Comment: I did this but it does not change anything.

Comment: Make some changes , hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, but I need to use multiple MaterialApps to have the color theme applied to all the different screens and widgets. Else I would be forced to manually add the same theme to each screen of the sub-app.

Comment: You can achieve that without using multiple materialapp function.

You don’t need to defined theme on each screen .

Just once defined your all theme in constant file and make model class for ThemeNotifier & use that in you app main file & whenever you want to change you’ve to just call notifylistener.

Refer some light-dark mode theme management

Answer (score 0):

As Dharini said you cannot use 2 material apps, but if you really want to, then here is the workaround for you

```
Issue: When you try to B(n) it pops the B as it is new material app.
|
|_ A
  |_ A1
  |_ A2
|_ B
  |_ B1
  |_B2
```

Resolution: Pass the BuildContext and Route from B to A and remove route on back tap of icon or android back key.

`Navigator.removeRoute(context, route);`

### Workaround

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(_AppA(_PageA(1)));
}

class _ColoredApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color color;
  final Widget home;
  final iosPageTransition = false;

  const _ColoredApp(this.color, this.home);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(primary: color),
        pageTransitionsTheme: iosPageTransition
            ? PageTransitionsTheme(
                builders: Map.fromIterable(
                  TargetPlatform.values,
                  value: (_) => const CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilder(),
                ),
              )
            : null,
      ),
      home: home,
    );
  }
}

class _AppA extends _ColoredApp {
  const _AppA(Widget home) : super(Colors.red, home);
}

class _AppB extends _ColoredApp {
  const _AppB(Widget home) : super(Colors.green, home);
}

class _PageA extends StatelessWidget {
  final int number;

  _PageA(this.number);

  final bRoutes = <BuildContext, Route>{};

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('A$number')),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: const Text('Next'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
              if (number > 2) {
                return WillPopScope(
                  onWillPop: () async {
                    if (number > 2 && bRoutes.isNotEmpty) {
                      Navigator.removeRoute(bRoutes.entries.last.key, bRoutes.entries.last.value);
                      bRoutes.remove(bRoutes.entries.last.key);
                      return false;
                    } else {
                      return true;
                    }
                  },
                  child: _AppB(_PageB(1, bRoutes)),
                );
              }
              return _PageA(number + 1);
            }));
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _PageB extends StatelessWidget {
  final int number;
  final Map<BuildContext, Route> bRoutes;

  const _PageB(this.number, this.bRoutes);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        leading: BackButton(onPressed: () {
                if (bRoutes.isNotEmpty) {
                  final context = bRoutes.entries.last.key;
                  final route = bRoutes.entries.last.value;
                  bRoutes.remove(bRoutes.entries.last.key);
                  Navigator.removeRoute(context, route);
                }
              })
            ,
        title: Text('B$number'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: const Text('Next'),
          onPressed: () {
            final route = MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
              return _PageB(number + 1, bRoutes);
            });

            bRoutes[context] = route;
            Navigator.push(context, route);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I see some problems with this approach:
1) It forces me to change all the pages and screens of the sub-apps in order to pass the routes parameter. I wanted to avoid to pass the theme for the same reason and this is why I use different MaterialApps.
2) There is no more page transition animation.
3) The iOS "swipe back" does not work in page B1.

Comment: Yes, Thats why I said it is a workaround, BTW why do you want to use 2 Material Apps?

Comment: My app contains different sub-apps, each with its color theme. Using a different MaterialApp for each sub-app is the simplest solution I found to apply the color to all pages and widgets.